# Calling simple mongo db function from a .js file --Solution now available

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongoose

If you are wondering how to call a server side function from a javascript file after a button is clicked here's how below. You have to use an HTTP request to call the server side end point. Then the end point calls the function. Also you need node installed. use npm install express to add in the dependency and also npm install nodemon. Make sure you have an active connection with MongoDb (I used a connection string between vs code and mongo). Modify the scheme to fit your specific data set aswell

server file

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import 'dotenv/config';

const app = express();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_CONNECT_STRING,
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB using Mongoose!');
});

app.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON bodies

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});

// define the schema
const documentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  title: String,
  artist: String,
  genre: String,
  popularity: Number,
  date: Date,
});

// Create the Document using the schema
const Document = mongoose.model('Songs', documentSchema);

// Endpoint to create a song
app.post('/create-song', async (req, res) => {
  const { title, artist, genre, popularity, date } = req.body;    //get in the parameters
  try {
    await createSong(title, artist, genre, popularity, date);   //call the func to upload to database
    res.status(200).send('Song created successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error uploading document:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
});
// Define the asynchronous function
async function createSong(title, artist, genre, popularity, dateString) {
  try {
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    // Create a new document instance
    const document = new Document({ title, artist, genre, popularity, date });
    // Save the document to the database
    await document.save();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  } finally {
    // Close the database connection
    mongoose.connection.close();
  }
}
```

js file that calls func

```
window.onload = function() {
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var artist = document.getElementById('artist');
    var genre = document.getElementById('genre');
    var rating = document.getElementById('rating');
    var released = document.getElementById('released');

    uploadSong();

    function uploadSong() {
      const songData = {
        title: title.value,
        artist: artist.value,
        genre: genre.value,
        popularity: rating.value,
        date: released.value
      };
      
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/create-song', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(songData)
      })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Song created successfully');
          } else {
            alert('Error:', response.statusText);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          alert('Error:', error.message);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The script running in the browser can't call the JS function on the server side directly. You need to use communicate with the server using HTTP requests.

Comment: @LinDu can you please show me an example of how to use HTTP requests for this specific case please. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: --------READ--------- I have figured out the solution and will update my code with the correct code so anyone ever having this same issue will see this.